# Flow of app within bottomsheet with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

[image: Where I'am now]

I'm trying to continue the flow of app within bottomsheet.

Case : When a user clicks any brand suppose "Levis" then it should display the brand products i.e. another fragment(containing Products data) within the same bottomsheet only.

Problem: the another fragment(containing Products data) is opening in a seperate frame not in the existing bottomsheet.

My code on adapter holder click event:

```
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String id = ld.getBrand_id();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("somekeyvalue", String.valueOf(id));

        Fragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) ct).getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }
});
```

I'm using Google material bottomsheet.

code to start bottomsheet:

```
BrandFragment bottomSheet = new BrandFragment();
bottomSheet.show(getChildFragmentManager(),
        "ModalBottomSheet");
```

Comment: you are using `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);` - does `R.id.frameLayout` belongs to bottomsheet?

Comment: I'm using this to start bottomsheet

        BrandFragment bottomSheet = new BrandFragment();
        bottomSheet.show(getChildFragmentManager(),
                "ModalBottomSheet");

Comment: this isn't answering my question at all... does `R.id.frameLayout` belongs to `Activity` or `BrandFragment`? btw. if you want to put `Fragment` inside another `Fragment` then you should use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: See to start a fragment within bottomsheet we don't need to pass any views like R.id.framelayout. We just need to pass the fragment we need to open

Comment: thats correct, but how this is related to my question? you are using `R.id.frameLayout` for loading into this frame `new ProductFragment`. Does `R.id.frameLayout` belongs to `Activity` or is it defined inside layout inflated by this `BrandFragment`

Comment: Brand Fragment layout contains R.id.frameLayout

Currently my code is showing Product Fragment in new view

I want to display the Product fragment in the same bottomsheet view.

Comment: can you show XMLs inflated by main `Activity` and `BrandFragment`? there is no duplicated `R.id.frameLayout` `id` in both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233504/discussion-between-user3081704-and-snachmsm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are loading `new ProductFragment()` into `R.id.frameLayout`, which probably belongs to `Activity`. if you want to open new `Fragment` inside another one then define container, which belongs to this first `Fragment`. also use then `getChildFragmentManager`, not `getSupportFragmentManager`

btw. ensure that `R.id.frameLayout` is unique and declared ONLY inside "parent" `Fragment`, not in `Activity`

Comment: Cannot resolve getChildFragmentManager inside adapter class

Comment: yep, it belongs to [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) as this is intended to load `Fragment` into another `Fragment`. `getSupportFragmentManager` belongs to `Activity` as intended to load `Fragment` into `Activity`

Comment: then what's the solution now?

Comment: pass `getChildFragmentManager` in adapters constructor